# How to make java file in java resources src directory programmatically

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-io

I have created 2 files. I am using eclipse editor.

**index.jsp**

```
<form action="InstallationSteps" method="post">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**InstallationSteps.java in java resources/src/pack.abc directory**

```
try {

        File yourFile = new File("/SiteConfig.java");
        if(!yourFile.exists()) {
            yourFile.createNewFile();
        } 

        FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream(yourFile,false); 
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fstream, "UTF-8");
        final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);

        out.write("package pack.abc; \n\n");
        out.write("public class SiteConfig {\n");
        out.write("final String JDBC_DRIVER             =   ''; \n");
        out.write("final String DB_URL                  =   ''; \n");
        out.write("final String DB_USER                 =   ''; \n");
        out.write("final String DB_PASS                 =   ''; \n");
        out.write("final String db_baseUrl              =   ''; \n");
        out.write("final String db_adminUrl             =   ''; \n");
        out.write("final String db_baseDirectoryPath    =   ''; \n");
        out.write("}");                 

        out.close();

    } catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("*****************************");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("*****************************");

    }
```

**Requirement**

I have to create new settings .java file in java resources/src or java resources/src/pack.abc directory

**Problem**

But when i execute above mentioned code then neither it produces any .java file nor any error. It is showing blank screen. How to create .java file in src directory?

Comment: From the "looks" of things, it's creating the file in the root directory. But I'm left scratching my head as to why you're going this route...

Comment: This is first installation step and i have to setup user database details. That is why i am creating SiteConfig.java Class programmatically

Comment: I can almost sense how I'm going to get called to clean this up

Comment: I would replace all the `\n` you have going on with `out.newLine();` What you're doing is literally going to write `\n` where you may not want it to go...

Comment: is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Configuration should be stored in configuration files, not in Java source code files. Java source code can in turn easily read configuration files and assign it as some application wide variable.

Comment: @BaqlusC how and where to make configuration files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace

```
File yourFile = new File("/SiteConfig.java");
```

to

```
File yourFile = new File("/yourWorkPlace/projectName/src/pack/abc/SiteConfig.java");
```

Comment: A fat -1 for a non-portable solution which only works in OP's very specific environment and nowhere else (and thus also not on the machines of the endusers the OP intend to distribute this "application" for).

Comment: @BalusC Your comment is very difficult to understand. Please write in simple words.